# boto3 get_secret_value not working with ARN

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager/client/get_secret_value.html

> SecretId (string) – [REQUIRED]
>
> The ARN or name of the secret to retrieve.
>
> For an ARN, we recommend that you specify a complete ARN rather than a partial ARN. See Finding a secret from a partial ARN.

I can't get this to work with the ARN though.

```py
import boto3

boto3.client("secretsmanager").get_secret_value(SecretId="arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:260890374087:secret/Datadog/ApiKey-s3xUqf")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Invalid name. Must be a valid name containing alphanumeric characters, or any of the following: -/_+=.@!
```

How do I retrieve the secret with the ARN?

Comment: This response can sent to client when the server replies with status code > 300. Are you correctly authenticated to AWS SDK?

Comment: What if you pass secretId as name of the secret?

Comment: Just tested with boto3 v1.26.93 and this worked correctly for both secret name and secret ARN. What `boto3.__version__` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the latest Python SDK Secrets Manager code example that includes this use case. This code has been tested and works. See here in AWS Code Example Github.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python/example_code/secretsmanager

In this code example, you do not need to reference the ARN.

Comment: The link now 404s.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I made a copy-paste error:

I had

```
"arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:260890374087:secret/Datadog/ApiKey-s3xUqf"
```

It should be:

```
"arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:260890374087:secret:Datadog/ApiKey-s3xUqf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the complete ARN of your secrets using boto3's `list_secret` operation or use the AWS CLI `aws secretsmanager list-secrets`, it is recommended to copy the complete ARN of the secret stored on SecretsManager instead of just partial ARN

Make sure that IAM user you are using with boto3 had permissions `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue`

I also suggest that you try upgrading your boto3 package

```
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

and, making sure that you have AWS CLI version 2 instead of version 1, this should help you test commands and operations before writing python script as both updated AWS CLI version 2 and latest version boto3 have the same functionalities when it comes to interacting with AWS API's

Answer (score 0):

In the `get_secret_value` method  `SecretId` parameter should be the ARN or name of the secret. For an ARN, it is recommended to specify a complete ARN rather than a partial ARN.

```
import boto3

response = boto3.client("secretsmanager").get_secret_value(SecretId="arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:260890374087:secret:Datadog/ApiKey-s3xUqf")
secret_value = response["SecretString"]

print(secret_value)
```

For the name of the secret, you need to get the secret name from the ARN and use it as the `SecretId`

```
import boto3

secret_name = "Datadog/ApiKey-s3xUqf"

response = boto3.client("secretsmanager").get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)
secret_value = response["SecretString"]

print(secret_value)
```